# Jsp code with mysql

Tags: jsp

I am facing the problem in mysql query. The query working fine in PHP MY admin.Whenever i am implementing through jsp code it is showing String literal is not properly closed error.

Here is my code

```
String query="SELECT * FROM (

                            (SELECT SupplierTicketId AS SupplierTicketId,
                                    TicketType AS TicketType,
                                    SupplierTicketStatus AS SupplierTicketStatus,
                                    CreatedBy AS CreatedBy,
                                    SupplierType AS SupplierType
                                    FROM supplierticket)
                           UNION ALL
                           (SELECT FactoryTicketId, TicketType, 
                                   FactoryTicketStatus, FactoryTicketCreatedBy,
                                   SupplierType
                                   FROM factoryticket)
                           )t";
```

Plz help me..What is problem in this query..Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot write multiline String literals in Java. Instead, you should either write a single line String argument as query (bad readibility), or concatenate several String literals. For the latter, you should use a `StringBuilder`. For example: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT"); sb.append(" * FROM "); sb.append(...);`

Comment: Remove that "t" from last.

Answer (score -1):

Use below query :-

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM (

                            (SELECT SupplierTicketId AS SupplierTicketId,
                                    TicketType AS TicketType,
                                    SupplierTicketStatus AS SupplierTicketStatus,
                                    CreatedBy AS CreatedBy,
                                    SupplierType AS SupplierType
                                    FROM supplierticket)
                           UNION ALL
                           (SELECT FactoryTicketId, TicketType, 
                                   FactoryTicketStatus, FactoryTicketCreatedBy,
                                   SupplierType
                                   FROM factoryticket)
                           )";
```

Comment: I tried this query.But it is showing following error.Multiple annotation found at this line.String literal is not properly closed..